# Sql server converter String hora para Decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida de como converto uma coluna string que traz a hora como '08:00:00' para decimal, exatamente como o  Excel faz, quando muda o formato para numero por exemplo:

'08:00:00' =  '0,33333333'

Desde já agradeço

Comment: E qual é a regra de conversão que você deseja implementar?

Comment: Amigos, a dúvida do colega é pertinente sim, tanto que há uma pergunta semelhante com a mesma negativação, porém as respostas possuem aprovações, o que indica utilidade nas respostas. @JoséDiz primeiramente, seja bem vindo ao forum. Acesse este link e efetue os devidos testes com as soluções apresentadas. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25526039/4616856

Answer (score 0):

Você pode dividir o valor por 86400 que é a quantidade de segundos no dia, mas antes disso deve converter para segundos

segue um exemplo completo:

```
Declare  @data As Datetime = '08:00:00'
        ,@H As Float
        ,@M As Float
        ,@S As Bigint
        ,@Result As Bigint

Set      @H = Datepart(hh,@data)*3600
Set      @M = Datepart(mi,@data)*60
Set      @s = Datepart(ss,@data)

Select   (@H + @M + @s) / 86400
```